# Google Cloud Engine - failed to curl a website locate in Iran from my VM instance

Tags: curl, wget, google-compute-engine

actually i can't curl / wget an iranian website

french.irib.ir

I use Google Cloud Compute engine with a Debian Server

The firewall is open...

Others URLs work

french.irib.ir

Can someone have a look from his instance?

from my personnal computer i can wget a default page and curl the RSS feed of this iranian site, why not from google VM?

Answer (score 0):

Due to export restrictions Google restricts access to and from some countries, including Iran.