# Getting connection time out when I run `curl` command on Google Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, curl, ssh, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I created a virtual machine and installed WordPress in it and pushed it to Google cloud. It is up and running at www.mobilesoft.asia.

I installed WooCommerce plugin in it in order to create my shop. Then I added a payment module like Paypal to handle payment transactions. The problem is when I try to buy a product the payment button doesn't react.

I opened SSH Console and tried to curl the URL that is get called when I click on payment button but I saw I'm getting connection time out. These are commands I ran

```
hesam@bitnami-wordpress-xxx:~$ curl http://www.parspal.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.parspal.com port 80: Connection timed out
hesam@bitnami-wordpress-xxx:~$ curl http://merchant.parspal.com/WebService.asmx?wsdl
curl: (7) Failed to connect to merchant.parspal.com port 80: Connection timed out
hesam@bitnami-wordpress-xxx:~$ curl https://merchant.parspal.com/WebService.asmx?wsdl
curl: (7) Failed to connect to merchant.parspal.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Parspal (the company I'm using their payment service) is saying your host is not able to connect to our webservice. Is it possible? What might be the cause of the issue?

When I run above commands on my local terminal I'm able to get something while I'm not able via SSH to my virtual machine. Does something needs to be configured on my compute engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.parspal.com` resolves to an IP address registered in Iran, and there are restrictions in place that prevent you from sending traffic to such addresses:

[Google Cloud Engine - failed to curl a website locate in Iran from my VM instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259799/)

Comment: Thanks @andreas, I'm aware of that but since I'm able to connect to another webservices from another company I thought there might be something wrong that I don't know why. So you mean if IP has been registered in Iran, then I'm not able to call the API and since other's are not registered in Iran then I'm able to connect to their webservices. Thanks man for shading the light :)

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the instance has an external IP Address or not. If not, it will not be able to communicate outside.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848820/routing-on-google-compute-engine-from-a-machine-that-doesnt-have-public-ip-to-t?rq=1) if it helps.

Comment: In this case if I run `curl www.google.com` I shouldn't be able to get anything, right? but I'm able to get html contents. But thanks for the I'll check it and update you if my problem fixed by that. Thanks.